# How to open emoji keyboard in flutter

Tags: flutter, keyboard, flutter-layout, emoji, flutter-dependencies

I am creating one chatting application and there I want to open the emoji keyboard when the user clicks on the emoji icon it will open the emoji keyboard. here are the image and I want to open the emoji keyboard on click on the left side emoji icon.

[image: in this picture there is one emoji icon and i want to open emoji keyboard on click of that icon]

Comment: Not default way to do, but try with it. working fine https://pub.dev/packages/emoji_picker#-readme-tab-

Comment: Yes, I've tried this emoji_picker but it won't pop up when I click on icon and close on icon pressed. so please tell me if you have any other solution.

Comment: Yup sure, i will update you today.

Comment: when i press and hold enter key on my android keyboard, brings and emoji keyboard. So am trying to change the key to an emoji face instead of keY.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [Emoji Picker](https://github.com/JeffG05/emoji_picker) for this, below is the complete example

[image]

```
import 'package:emoji_picker/emoji_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MainApp());

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Test",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Emoji Picker Test"),
        ),
        body: MainPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MainPageState createState() => new MainPageState();
}

class MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  bool isShowSticker;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    isShowSticker = false;
  }

  Future<bool> onBackPress() {
    if (isShowSticker) {
      setState(() {
        isShowSticker = false;
      });
    } else {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }

    return Future.value(false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              // your list goes here

              // Input content
              buildInput(),

              // Sticker
              (isShowSticker ? buildSticker() : Container()),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      onWillPop: onBackPress,
    );
  }

  Widget buildInput() {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          // Button send image
          Material(
            child: new Container(
              margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1.0),
              child: new IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.image),
                onPressed: () {},
                color: Colors.blueGrey,
              ),
            ),
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          Material(
            child: new Container(
              margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1.0),
              child: new IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.face),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    isShowSticker = !isShowSticker;
                  });
                },
                color: Colors.blueGrey,
              ),
            ),
            color: Colors.white,
          ),

          // Edit text
          Flexible(
            child: Container(
              child: TextField(
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueGrey, fontSize: 15.0),
            decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
              hintText: 'Type your message...',
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueGrey),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),

      // Button send message
      Material(
        child: new Container(
          margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
          child: new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.send),
            onPressed: () {},
            color: Colors.blueGrey,
          ),
        ),
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    ],
  ),
  width: double.infinity,
  height: 50.0,
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      border: new Border(
          top: new BorderSide(color: Colors.blueGrey, width: 0.5)),
      color: Colors.white),
    );
  }

  Widget buildSticker() {
    return EmojiPicker(
  rows: 3,
  columns: 7,
  buttonMode: ButtonMode.MATERIAL,
  recommendKeywords: ["racing", "horse"],
  numRecommended: 10,
  onEmojiSelected: (emoji, category) {
    print(emoji);
  },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable answer i've added bottom sheet and then use this emoji picker and it works fine :)

Comment: became slow when fetching recent.

Comment: @b.john did you manage to modify it, to make it fast?

Comment: @b.john did you manage to modify it, to make it fast?

Comment: no, i didnt. I used this one,  I left the feature instead. If you hold an enter key on your android keyboard, emojis appear. If you find a way out please comment again.

Comment: `Emoji_Picker` is not smooth. I am not recommended this plugin

Comment: This plugin is very laggy, i would not suggest if you want to make fully smooth app. also this plugin increases the size of app, not durable and efficient. Although no pressure!!

Comment: The mentioned library is outdated. Use https://pub.dev/packages/emoji_picker_flutter instead.