# How to make an emoji picker in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make an emoji picker.

I've searched Google and referred some Stack Overflow questions, but still can't do it.

I've used the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58370957/16124033), but it doesn't work. It shows blank (not white, it's transparent)

My code:

```
Offstage(
  offstage: false,
  child: SizedBox(
    height: 250,
    child: EmojiPicker(
      onEmojiSelected: (category, emoji) {
        messageTextController.text = messageTextController.text + emoji.emoji;
      },
      onBackspacePressed: () {},
      config: Config(
        columns: 7,
        verticalSpacing: 0,
        horizontalSpacing: 0,
        initCategory: Category.SMILEYS,
        bgColor: AppColors.kIconColor,
        indicatorColor: Colors.blue,
        iconColor: Colors.grey,
        iconColorSelected: Colors.blue,
        showRecentsTab: true,
        recentsLimit: 28,
        tabIndicatorAnimDuration: kTabScrollDuration,
        categoryIcons: const CategoryIcons(),
        buttonMode: kIsWeb || Platform.isAndroid ? ButtonMode.MATERIAL : ButtonMode.CUPERTINO,
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

How do I make an emoji picker in Flutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dependencies:
  emoji_picker_flutter: ^1.4.1
```

Add this Version hope now it will work

Comment: Sorry, I forgot

Answer (score 0):

The package you are using has been **discontinued** 2 years ago and it doesn't even support `null safety` so it is bound to fail at some point. What you should do instead is try searching pub.dev for other `emoji pickers` if created by other developers like this one: [emoji_picker_flutter: ^1.5.1](https://pub.dev/packages/emoji_picker_flutter) and there are others as well if you have trouble in this one(which you won't) at pub.dev as I mentioned above

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! I'm using `emoji_picker_flutter` and I'm having a problem (this question)